# Validation rule on email global action

Tags: email, formula, validation, leads, apex-email-service

I have a requirement where the users will be sending outbound emails from lead, opportunity and other custom object records.

Now, the recipients of these emails will be internal salesforce users, but will not be related to that record. As of now, users are manually removing the record from to-address and are composing the to address. But I'm afraid, they might accidentally trigger the email without clearing record from to-address

[image: email]

I would like to create a validation rule where it checks for record in to-address and throws an error that "email cannot be sent to this user" so that users will always send the email to correct recipient by removing the record from to-address field.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not looking to leverage it on certain objects, you can create your own `Email` quick action that does what you're looking to do. In this case, it'd set the identified field to null and replace the standard email action on the page layout.

1. Create Email Quick Action
   [image: List item]
2. Set predefined fields (`To` = NULL)
   [image]
3. Remove existing `Email` quick action on page layout and add in the custom one you created above. Both labels will be `Email`, but if you hover over it you'll see the name you set to pick the correct one.

[image]